# How do I install python3 in docker with golang as my base image?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

My docker file looks something like this:

```
# Start from a Debian image with the latest version of Go installed
# and a workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
FROM golang

# Install our Go dependencies
RUN go get -u golang.org/x/oauth2...
ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/...
```

My base application will be running on golang,but I need to access a python script from golang for some processing. How do I install python3 in my docker container and install some of python dependencies using pip .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're indeed using a debian image like this one:

https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/cffcff7fce7f6b6b5c82fc8f7b3331a10590a661/1.9/stretch/Dockerfile

Which is tag: `golang:1.9-stretch`

Debian stretch comes with python3 already https://wiki.debian.org/Python

So no further action is required. You would need to install pip however and then continue as normal.

Comment: I have tried this image. `python3` yields `/bin/sh: 1: python3: not found`

Answer (score 3):

You can install python3 on [official golang docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang) by adding following lines to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-setuptools
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use DataDog go-python3 module and this worked for me

```
FROM golang:1.19-buster
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt -y update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt install -y python3-pip
RUN apt install -y python3-dev
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```

- Debian Buster has python3 installed by default: https://wiki.debian.org/Python
- I had to install python3-dev to have the header files of Python C API in pkgconfig.
- Eventually exporting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable made it work.